# Websphere MQ message put time to remote queue

Tags: ibm-mq

Suppose a message is put to local MQ manager, say, MQR 1, which forward the message to a remote MQ manager, say MQR 2. When an application, say reader, gets the message from MQR2, what is the put time?

I use to think put time is the time the message is put to the local queue from reader's perspective, i.e. MQR2 in this example. But I notice weird situation that the message just arrives has put time about two hours ago. This make me think it is the time when the message is put to MQR 1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put date and time are set when the message is put on the queue. If the message 'travels' further to a remote queuemanger, the time and date is NOT updated and reflects the 'original' put time and date when the message was put on the queue. The fields belong to the initially created mq message.

> For the MQPUT and MQPUT1 calls, the application can specify any value. The queue manager transmits this value with the message and delivers it to the application that issues the get request for the message.

from: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.12/gtpc2/mqmdst.html

Comment: Thank you. Then is there any way to see when the message arrives at my local queue?